# How to install a script from browser to mobile phone and run it?

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, web

What i want to do is this -

When i open a webpage on my mobile browser, the webpage should download and run a script on my device.
The script would be in the native language (like Objective C for iOS devices etc.) or maybe it would be in a single language.
Simple as that.

So, is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: That's not possible. JavaScript may run in script tags but you won't be able to inject code into devices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this topic looks shady

Comment: umm, okay, but is there some other way?

Comment: haha, i just want to do this for my devices...:p

Answer (score 2):

Speaking for Android, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious security reasons. You are welcome to distribute an Android app via a Web site, but the user will still have to agree to install it, and then it will only run if and when the user runs it.

Comment: None other way possible?

Comment: @Ashish: You are welcome to run JavaScript in the Web browser itself (unless the user disabled it in the browser, of course). Anything else would be a massive security flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for iOS, this is not possible. iOS is designed to be as secure as possible with sandboxed environments for all natively run iOS code.

The closest thing to a script is a JavaScript web script which will not do you justice.

You won't be able to inject code to devices unless you enroll in an Apple Enterprise Development Program and allow your users to *download* an app to run code. Furthermore, the downloaded app can only run sandboxed.